# How can you correct values of a list in increasing/decreasing order in python

Tags: python, list

there are a lot of list like below but need to be corrected.

`[0, 0, 0, 5, 5, 0, 6, 6, 7, 7, 7, 7, 8, 8, 8, 11, 9, 9, 9, 9, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 14, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 8, 8, 8, 8, 7, 7, 7, 7, 6, 6, 6, 6, 5, 5, 5, 5, 4, 4, 4, 4, 3, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]`

all lists share some common features:

1- of each value, there are more than two number[ if it is only one it is probably wrong.] Note that there is a wrong 0 in  `5, 5, 0, 6, 6` which must be `5, 5, 6, 6, 6` or the wrong 14 in  `12, 12, 12, 14, 11, 11, 11, 11` which is 11 or 12.

2- values of all list are increasing / decreasing or both [increase in some part and decrease in some other]: Note that the list is starting from 5,6,7 to 12 and then decreasing to 3.

3- wrong number can repeat two times for example:

`[0, 0, 8, 0, 0, 0, 12, 12, 6, 6, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 6, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 9, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 5, 5, 5, 5, 0]`

Note that in  `0, 0, 0, 12, 12, 6, 6, 0, 0, 0, 0,` all `12, 12, 6, 6` are wrong and should be 0

4-two continues values are not allowed to change  more than one. if changing suddenly from 0 to 4 for example in `0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 4, 4, 4`  that should be `0,1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4`

First i tried:

```
for i in range(1,len(lis)-1):
    if lis[i+1] == lis [i-1]:
        lis[i]= lis[i+1]
```

which worked well for single values, but didn't worked for wrong edge values like `12, 12, 12, 14, 11, 11, 11, 11`

then i tried:

```
for i in range(1,len(lis)):
    if not (lis[i]-lis[i-1]==1 or lis[i]-lis[i-1]==-1):
        lis[i]=lis[i-1]
```

that actually doesn't work :| Because it recognize the initiation point as a wrong value. in `0, 4, 4, 4` 0-4 is more than one.

Finally, i tried:

```
for i in range(1,len(lis)-1):
    if lis[i+1]== [i-1]:
        lis[i]=lis[i-1]
    if not(lis[i-1]-lis[i]==1 or  lis[i-1]-lis[i]==-1):
        if not (lis[i-1] ==0 ):
            lis[i]=lis[i-1]
```

it works well but still there is problem with:

-repeated wrong between 0s like:  `0, 0, 0, 12, 12, 6, 6, 0, 0, 0, 0,`

- initial and termination point that there is a jump like: `0, 4, 4, 4`

Any Idea how to solve these problem?

Comment: `0, 0, 0, 12, 12, 6, 6, 0, 0, 0, 0` how do you know this is wrong, since it follow the rule #1 and #2 you specified

Comment: and rule number #4 is just confused, is that you mean the  change must happen either +1 or -1, like this one should be wrong due to #4  `4, 4, 4, 3, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0` ?

Comment: thanks for your comment Phung, First: rule #1 say 'more than two' and and about rule #2 you are right i must say there is just one increase/decrease wave in data, you see they are all increasing from 4 to 10 then decrease to 5? and this ```12,12,6,6``` doesn't really fit there. Second: yes , you got it, that should be ```4,4,4,3,3,3,2,2,2,1,1,1,0```